# Set UAC Level with PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, powershell, uac

I'm looking for a way to set the UAC Level with Powershell/Command prompt. I'm aware the 'EnableLUA' value in the registry, but this won't set the level. It's just true or false.

Is there a way to set the UAC Level with Powershell? With level, I mean the four levels of UAC. They go from 'Never Notify' to 'Always Notify".

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several registry values that control User Account Control:

1. FilterAdministratorToken
2. ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin
3. ConsentPromptBehaviorUser
4. EnableInstallerDetection
5. ValidateAdminCodeSignatures
6. EnableLUA
7. PromptOnSecureDesktop
8. EnableVirtualization

The combination of these values is what controls the slider in the GUI, or vice-versa.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232771.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Actually there already existed a takeaway powershell script to you can make use of.

You can easily find  them in [How to switch UAC level](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-switch-UAC-level-0ac3ea11)

Hopefully, it can help.

**Edit**

The code from the mentioned Microsoft Technet site implements these cmdlets:

- Set-UACLevel()
- Get-UACLevel()

But they are not confirmed for this OS (12. Jan. 2017):

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows 7

Code snippet:

```
New-Variable -Name Key 
New-Variable -Name PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name 
New-Variable -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
 
Function Set-RegistryValue($key, $name, $value, $type="Dword") {  
  If ((Test-Path -Path $key) -Eq $false) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $key | Out-Null }  
       Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name $name -Value $value -Type $type  
}  
 
Function Get-RegistryValue($key, $value) {  
   (Get-ItemProperty $key $value).$value  
}  
 
$Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" 
$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name = "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name = "PromptOnSecureDesktop" 
 
Function Get-UACLevel(){ 
    $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
    $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name 
    If($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 0 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
        "Never notIfy" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
        "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(do not dim my desktop)" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
        "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(default)" 
    } 
    ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 2 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
        "Always notIfy" 
    } 
    Else{ 
        "Unknown" 
    } 
} 
     
Function Set-UACLevel() { 
    Param([int]$Level= 2) 
 
    New-Variable -Name PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value 
    New-Variable -Name ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value 
 
    If($Level -In 0, 1, 2, 3) { 
        $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5 
        $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
        Switch ($Level)  
        {  
          0 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 0  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 0 
          }  
          1 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 0 
          }  
          2 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 5  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
          }  
          3 { 
              $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = 2  
              $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = 1 
          }  
        } 
        Set-RegistryValue -Key $Key -Name $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name -Value $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value 
        Set-RegistryValue -Key $Key -Name $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name -Value $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value 
 
        Get-UACLevel 
    } 
    Else{ 
        "No supported level" 
    } 
     
} 
 
Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-UACLevel 
Export-ModuleMember -Function Set-UACLevel
```

Comment: I can confirm Set-UACLevel 0 works on Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much, I got it. The following .REG file will set the UAC to Level 2.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000005
"ConsentPromptBehaviorUser"=dword:00000003
"EnableInstallerDetection"=dword:00000001
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001
"EnableVirtualization"=dword:00000001
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:00000001
"ValidateAdminCodeSignatures"=dword:00000000
"FilterAdministratorToken"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will set to Level 1 (Much like the answer above me)
Level 1 is the same as Level 2 but does not black out the screen (Better for remote desktop usage etc)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000005
"ConsentPromptBehaviorUser"=dword:00000003
"EnableInstallerDetection"=dword:00000001
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000001
"EnableVirtualization"=dword:00000001
"PromptOnSecureDesktop"=dword:00000000
"ValidateAdminCodeSignatures"=dword:00000000
"FilterAdministratorToken"=dword:00000000
```